# how to get first value of arraylist and pas as parameter

Tags: android

how to pass ArrayList index 0 value as parameter to another screen help me please

```
    int counter=Category_name.size();
if(counter==1)
{
    static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> Menu_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
    Intent iMenuList = new Intent(MenuGroup.this, thirdstep.class);
    String s = Menu_ID[index0];
    String t = Category_name[index0];
    iMenuList.putExtra("Menu_ID",s);
    iMenuList.putExtra("menu_group", t);
    startActivity(iMenuList);
}
```

Comment: do you want to pass full list or only 1st value?

Comment: only first value in arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that some null values are getting added in the list as you are reading from the JSON and you want to take the first non null values.

Solutions:
1. When you parse the JSON add only the non null values to the list and then use list.get(0).
Or
2. Once the list is formed, iterate through the list. Check for null condition, pick the first non null value and put in your string and break the loop.

Comment: how to pick first non null value from list??

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = Menu_ID.get(0);
String t = Category_name.get(0);
```

**EDIT**

You cant add a single value on any index but 0, here is a simple example

```
ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
Category_name.add(5, "string");
```

console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: suppose if my arraylist contain single value but dont know at which index then what will i do how to dynamically identify index and pass as parameter/

Comment: Use Menu_ID.add() to add data with increamental index, and Menu_ID.remove() to sort data automatically after removal\

Comment: but in my case in dynamically load list from http json and pas as parameter so dontknow at which position arrayindex same i only know that value is single may b is index(0) or index(1) or index(3)

Comment: well, if you have only 1 item in the list be sure it's always at index 0, otherwise it throws a IndexOutOfBoundsException, I'll provide an example in my answe

Comment: i used count check my code above so it is correct?what ever index of value  is always show at position zero???

Comment: yes if there is only one item it will be on index zero and before asking a question you can format your code, eclipse will be glad to do that for you ctrl+shift+f